# What is useHref and useResolvedPath for

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

Who can show by examples where `useHref` and `useResolvedPath` are used ?

Answer (score -1):

- [`useHref`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-href) - The useHref hook returns a URL that may be used to link to the given to location, even outside of React Router.
- [`useResolvedPath`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-resolved-path) - This hook resolves the pathname of the location in the given to value against the pathname of the current location.
  This is useful when building links from relative values. For example, check out the source to  which calls useResolvedPath internally to resolve the full pathname of the page being linked to.